# Multiple UITableView but some rows smaller than others

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview, row-height

I have multiple UITableViews for layout purposes on the screen. These are functionally working fine, I'm just boggled as to why they are displaying differently.

My 3 table views are: **loginTableView**, **forgotPass** and **openAccount** The delegate and datasource of all 3 is file's owner. This is what I have on the viewDidLoad:

```
 #define TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT 50;
 loginTableView.rowHeight = TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
 forgotPass.rowHeight = TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
 openAccount.rowHeight = TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
```

The **loginTableView** cells show up fine but the other two tables' cells are smaller in height than it. I'm using a custom method to create the cells (same method for all tables) and I can't spot any difference between how the different tables are set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - it looks like the correct table view had "Separator = None" set in interface builder where the other two table views did not. This was adding a separator and making them the tiniest bit smaller than the other table view.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
}
```

try implementing this method in your tableView delegate.